# Is there any single word expression that means "same"

Tags: word-choice

I understand this is casual English to say "same" after someone says they do something, but I was wondering if there was a close expression in Japanese that isn't just like `私も`. I've heard there's `それな` but that applies more to the usage where you agree with someone, not that you do the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could say 同感{どうかん}. A longer way would be 私もそう思う.